# concatenate multi records in pig

Tags: hbase, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I want to concatenate all records using Pig. 
After load in the data with "pigStorage" and '-tagFile' label, my data looks like:

```
(filename, aaaaaaaaaaa)
(filename, bbbbbbbbbbbbbb)
```

And the result I prefer is:

```
(filename, aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbb)
```

Then I can store the data into HBase with filename as rowkey.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP the data by the filename and then use [BagToString](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#bagtostring) to CONCAT all bags to a single string.

```
B = GROUP A BY filename;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,BagToString(A.$1,'');
DUMP C;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I`ve tried this and I got (filename, {(filename,aaaaaaaa),(filename, bbbbbbbbbbb)}. I also tried to remove filename insides the tuple, and got (filename, {(aaaaaaaaa),(bbbbbbbbbbbb)}